# Set thrift output directory without Java style directory structure

Tags: .net, thrift

I have a project where I intend to use Thrift and I want a prebuild hook that generates my code in a directory that does not match the namespace required in my code file. I have tried both `-o` and `-out` but neither give the intended behavior I require. I could accomplish this through a series of additional build steps however it would be nicer if it could be done in one line with parameters. I've looked at the help and have searched around and don't see a way to accomplish this directly. It is a C# .NET project.

The current result for a file with namespace `com.example.plop`:

```
-(out directory)
  - com
    - example
      - plot
        - my generated files
```

Desired output:

```
- (out directory)
  -foo
    - my generated files
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this in the thrift file by using the `namespace` function:

```
namespace java com.example.plot.gen
namespace rb foo
```

Now for files for Ruby will be in:

```
- (out directory)
  -foo
    - my generated files
```